# Getting syntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: json, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularJS. Few moments earlier the below code was working fine. Don't know what changes I have made that now it's giving me JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data in response
 Could you please take a look over the below codes?

```
  <!doctype html>

       <html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
       <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0  /angular.min.js"></script>
       <script src="controller.js"></script>
    </head><body>
    <div ng-controller="people">
    <ul>
        <h2> I need to learn AngularJS </h2>
        <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
             {{ person.name + ' : ' + person.age}}
         </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

JS file

```
  var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
  app.controller('people' , function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('http://127.0.0.1/garg/database.json')
  .success(function(response){
   $scope.persons = response.records;
   });
   });
```

Json file

```
            {
                "records":[
            { 
                "name": "rock",
                "age" : "40"

            },
            {
                "name": "undertaker",
                "age" : "40"


            },
            { 
                "name": "kane",
                "age" : "40"


            },
            { 
                "name": "triple h",
                "age" : "40"


            }
            ]
            }
```

Comment: Works for me. There are 2 extra spaces in the url you use for angularjs. Is it a copy/paste mistake ?

Comment: Yes, it's copy/paste mistake. It was working for me also. But now I don't  know why it's behaving like that. :(

Comment: Could you paste complete error message please ?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1/json/database.json. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). Could this be the reason?

Comment: Yes, how do you access your HTML file ?

Comment: I am using Xampp: apache server. I just started apache server and mysql. Put my files in htcdocs. That's it. I don't know how it worked that time and now why it;s stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access your HTML file using the same domain/ip as the one in your AJAX call. For instance, use this in your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('people' , function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://127.0.0.1/garg/database.json')
    .success(function(response){
        $scope.persons = response.records;
    });
});
```

and access your HTML file with this URL: http://127.0.0.1/garg/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot man :). I was accessing my file using localhost/garg/index.html. Didn't have any  idea using the ip would make  this much difference.